# Spring Boot Jpa and Jdbc configuration not working as expected

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a Spring-boot application which needs to create a brand new database and get some information from another, so I think I need configurate **two** *datasources*.

After a few intents to create what I wanna do and having no success here are some questions and code I have created so far, please guide me if I'm wrong on the configuration.

First question, despite that the new database is gonna use **jpa**, and the existing a **jdbctemplate**, the config file is still the same for both right?
Here is my config class file:

**DbConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class DbConfig {

@Bean(name="bitacoraDb")
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("bitacora.datasource")
public DataSourceProperties bitacoraDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties("bitacora.datasource")
public DataSource bitacoraDataSource() {
    return bitacoraDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
}

@Bean(name="siaDb")
@ConfigurationProperties("sia.datasource")
public DataSource siaDataSource() {

    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

@Bean(name="siaJdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("siaDb") DataSource dataSource) {

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);

    return jdbcTemplate;
}
}
```

Then, my **application.properties**, here I don't know if hibernate properties are working correctly:

```
bitacora.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.202:5432/bitacorapp
bitacora.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
bitacora.datasource.username=argos_admin
bitacora.datasource.password=argos@27467
bitacora.jpa.hibernate.show_sql=true
bitacora.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true
bitacora.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor=org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor
bitacora.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
bitacora.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

# --------------------
# Second datasource
# --------------------
sia.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.202:5432/argosrr-serv
sia.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
sia.datasource.username=argos_admin
sia.datasource.password=argos@27467
```

The thing is that the new database is created in the second datasource which I don't want to, but my controllers and repositories works as expected, but I need to separate the databases.
I don't know if after solve this problem it could lead to some others because the bad configuration.

Thanks for your help.